# iOS archiving object works on device but not on simulator

Tags: ios, simulator, nskeyedarchiver

I am using the usual code for NSKeyedArchiver, saving and loading a single NSMutableArray. On my iPhone and iPad I get the full array back; on the simulator, I get an empty array. Not nil, but a valid array that is just empty. Elsewhere in the app, other archiving works fine on simulator and devices.

I am including the code on the off chance that there is a lurking bug, but I am puzzled.

```
- (NSString*) personImageArchivePath {
    NSArray* docFolderPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                              NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* docFolderPath = docFolderPaths[0];
    return [docFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"personImage.archive"];
}

- (void) savePersonImages {
    NSLog(@"Archiving %ld person images", (unsigned long)self.personImages.count);
    BOOL success = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:self.personImages 
                                               toFile:[self personImageArchivePath]];
    NSString* result = success ? @"succeeded" : @"failed";
    NSLog(@"saving person images %@", result);

    // Sanity check
    NSMutableArray* reloadedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver 
        unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self personImageArchivePath]];
    if (reloadedArray == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Sanity check: No person images found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Sanity check: Unarchived %ld person images", 
                (unsigned long)reloadedArray.count);
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray*) loadPersonImages
{
    return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self personImageArchivePath]];
    // This returns nil (of course) on first launch, all platforms.
    // On the devices subsequent calls return the full array that was archived;
    // on the simulator they return an empty array.
}
```

Comment: What is the type of element in `self.personImages`.

Comment: An NSMutableArray. That class does conform to NSCoding, so it should work as the root object for NSKeyedArchiver. And, it does work on my devices.

Comment: I added in some sanity-check code (above, and in the executable) and get an insane result: the save claims to be successful, but immediately reloading the saved data yields an empty array. Here are the NSLogs, with the prefix fluff removed:

    `Archiving 5 person images`
    `saving person images succeeded`
    `Sanity check: Unarchived 0 person images`

Comment: Oh, @KudoCC I didn't answer your question correctly. The type of element the array stores is UIImages.

Comment: Some more evidence: the problem was appearing in Xcode6-Beta5. It vanishes in Xcode5 -- that is, the simulator and devices behave the same. I am now installing the 7.1 simulator inside Xcode6 and will advise ASAP. (Slow download.)